# angular parse html to array

Tags: angular, parsing, typescript

How can I parse html into an array of entities?

Example: '`hello <strong>man</strong>`' => ['`hello`', '`<strong>`', '`man`', '`</strong>`']

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `split` Operator like so: `htmlString.split(/(<[^<>]*>)/)`.